# possible bug in python3 (or im dumb), reversing < and > gives error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

```
placement = "Beaches are cool places to visit in spring however the Mackinaw Bridge is near. Most people visit Mackinaw later since the island is a cool place to explore."
d = {}

for char in placement:
    if char not in d:
        d[char] = 0
        
    d[char] = d[char] + 1
min_value = d['B']
for char2 in d:
    if d[char2] < min_value:
        min_value = char2
        
print(d)
```

this works fine, but this doesnt:

```
product = "iphone and android phones"
lett_d = {}

for char in product:
    if char not in lett_d:
        lett_d[char] = 0

    lett_d[char] = lett_d[char] + 1

max_value = lett_d['i']
for char2 in lett_d:
    if lett_d[char2] > max_value:
        max_value = char2

print(lett_d)
```

the later returns a error in pycharm:

```
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'
```

i dont understand how this could be caused and have been trying to figure it out for an hour, i found another solution, but i want to know why reversing the > < will cause such a error, thanks in advance :)

Comment: Without even reading the code I can tell you that it's not a bug in Python.

Comment: What are you even trying to do with your code?

Comment: i just want to learn python, please i just want to know whats wrong with it

Comment: `char2` is a string. When you do `max_value = char2` you change `max_value` into a string too. The first code works only by chance.

Comment: oh... now it get it

Comment: Here's some advice: whenever you encounter something unexpected, _always_ assume there is a bug in _your_ code or _your_ understanding. Yes, Python has bugs (like all software does) but with its extensive history, many contributors, and global reach, it is _much_ more likely to be correct than you, a single person currently learning the language.

Answer (score 3):

The first one is just as broken as the second one; it just so happens that the condition `if d[char2] < min_value` is never true (because no letter occurs fewer times than `B`). If the second string were `"zulu warriors are cool"`, it would *also* seem to work.

The problem is that `min_value` is supposed to track the minimum count, so it must be an integer. But by assigning `min_value = char2` it is set to a string instead.

You probably meant `min_value = d[char2]`.

And if you want not only the minimum count, but also the corresponding character, you need to track that in a second variable.

Comment: Thomas, I expanded on the reason why the broken first one *seemed* to be okay, hope you don't mind.

Comment: @paxdiablo Not at all, thank you! I made it a bit more precise :)

Comment: i think there was a misunderstanding, wanted to get a key (the string) as my answer, the minvalue and maxvalue where supposed to give me the keys, not the values (due to bad naming), i dont know why the first one would be wrong, i dont get it

Comment: also, i got minvalue as x, x only appeared once, so the first code worked

Comment: @Flyingcar14 The first code worked by accident *for that specific input*, not because the code is correct. "x" is the last entry in the dictionary so the loop ends before it tries to compare it to a number. If you run the first code but change the `placement` string to something else it won't work. If you get why the second code doesn't work then surely you get why the first code is wrong too because it has the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to maybe find the most and least occurring character in your text. [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to the rescue (though it should be noted this doesn't take into account multiple characters sharing the same "rank").

```
>>> import collections
>>> text = "iphone and android phones"
>>> counts = collections.Counter(text)
Counter({'n': 4, 'o': 3, ' ': 3, 'd': 3, 'i': 2, 'p': 2, 'h': 2, 'e': 2, 'a': 2, 'r': 1, 's': 1})
>>> (most_common_ch, most_common_count), *_, (least_common_ch, least_common_count) = counts.most_common()
>>> most_common_ch, most_common_count, least_common_ch, least_common_count
('n', 4, 's', 1)
```

Comment: nope, im learning this on runestone and i got pissed af trying to learn the dictionary exercises, i just want to know how the     does reversing the < > signs change the entire code, i couldnt figure it out... still thanks tho